# How to approach this: Percentage change in one KPI leading to change in other KPIs?

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics

I want to know how can I approach or model this problem. I have 7 KPIs (3 of them dependent on each other) and one main KPI (total 8 KPIs). I want to understand effect of these 7 KPIs on the main KPIs.

End goal is to make the statement, if you vary KPI_1 by xx.xx %, main_KPI will vary by yy.yy%. Can I model this with linear regression, find coefficients or is there any better approach?

Comment: 1) Are your variables all numeric? 2) Do you have the ability to alter/generate your data or do you have a static provided dataset?

Comment: mostly numeric variables, I can alter dataset, but currently concentrating on static data I have. How do I find its weightage effect on target KPI, is there any literature, method I should read? For example what if I fit regression model and find the coefficients for each KPI wrt target KPI? or is there any better way to follow?

Answer (score 1):

The two key terms you should look up for your question are `counterfactual inference` and `treatment effects`.

### Counterfactuals

- [Counterfactual inference](https://www.inference.vc/causal-inference-3-counterfactuals/): A branch of causality which is concerned with answering 'What If' style questions.
- For example, what would the outcome have been if Patient A had taken Drug A instead of Drug B?
- This involves using our data to build up a causal diagram which describes our data. Tweaking a variable and observing the downstream impact on our target.
- This causal approach seems particularly relevant for your use case since:

  A) You can interfere with and manipulate the data.

  B) Your input variables have effects on each other.
- Hence, changing variable 1 might impact variable 8 directly but also impact variable 4 which in turn has its own knock on effect on variable 8.
- This is more robust than the flawed approach of 'Hold everything else constant and wiggle 1 variable at a time'.

### Treatment Effects

[Treatment effects](https://economics.mit.edu/files/32#:%7E:text=The%20term%20%27treatment%20effect%27%20refers,of%20scientific%20or%20policy%20interest.&text=A%20%27treatment%20effect%27%20is%20the,of%20scientific%20or%20policy%20interest.) are related to counterfactuals but a more general term for the class of problems you are trying to solve and may be productive to search for.

### Linear Regression

Regarding the suggestion of fitting a linear regression model and using coefficients to determine effect sizes. This may be useful but also may break down if some assumptions are not satisfied.

For example, we are assuming the data is well described by a linear model and that there are no interactions between the input data.